# Installing drain in wood floor

Tags: plumbing, drain, installation, caulking

I am installing a drainpan in an upstairs, wood floored laundry room to go under the stacked washer and dryer. I have built the pan of glued and screwed 1/2" plywood bottom and 1x3 sides. The joints are all siliconed and inside painted with several coats of Redgard. The plan is to drill through the floor to connect a drain in the box to a drain downstairs that has a gooseneck already.

I am attaching an edited diagram from another poster who had a similar project.

My plan is to cut a bevelled hole in the 1/2" bottom of the pan in which to set the drain, then Redgard the bevel and caulk between the bevel and the ABS drain.

My question is:
Is silicone adequate to caulk between the Redgarded plywood and the ABS drain? My considerations are adhesion, durability and flexibility. The drain has to be located beneath the washer so can't be inspected once installed so while I hope the drain never has to be used, it does have to remain intact.[image]

Comment: You should use a drain designed for a plastic shower pan, one with a bottom flange and rubber washer that will seal well to the bottom of your pan.   The silicone (or whatever  you use) then provides a secondary barrier, and in your case mainly protects the pan itself since it's made of wood.   Why don't you just buy one from plastic?????

Comment: Jay613 - None of the commercially available pans I found were large enough and none drained through the bottom. The reviews of plastic ones said they cracked and also the bottoms were not flat so not appropriate for a heavy washer. I am not concerned about the pan I built as it is completely sealed. I wouldn't use it in something like a shower where it would be continually exposed to water but in this application, it should be fine.

Comment: Great.  Well, get rid of that drain and use one with a rubber washer underneath, then flexible caulk is a good idea above that.

Comment: Other than maybe costing a little more, why not use a shower base with proper accommodation for a drain?

Comment: The pan is already built and sealed with Redgard so I don't really want to start over and the drain placement has to line up inside a currently open wall in the room below and tie in with the drain in that wall. We will drill a pilot hole up from below and that's where the drain goes.  Mainly, I am looking for suggestions for how to get the best seal around the drain for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [shower drain kit](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-Round-No-Caulk-White-PVC-Shower-Drain-with-4-1-4-in-Round-Snap-In-Stainless-Steel-Drain-Cover-420992/100346664#overlay).   Linked one is sample with no special recommendation, except it's on-point: it froms a mechanical seal with a rubber washer from underneath, and it's cheap.

[image]

You need to buy one with enough threading to accommodate the thickness of your home-made pan.

Also, in the link and photo below no attempt is made to seal the top half of the drain to the shower.  In your case, because your pan is made from wood, you should use caulk or plumber's putty to seal the top flange to the top of the base.

Below the floor, us an air gap to feed into an existing fixture, that way you don't need a trap.

*Note* not all shower drains work this way.  To state the obvious, get one that does.